What is the title of the movie about midget size Monsters that lives in the underground that is scared of light
Im trying to search the title of the movie that i watched and scared the shit out of me when i was a kid. Its about monsters(midget size or a bit taller) that lives in the underground and scared of light, i remember that the people in the movie are using flashlights as a weapon against them. In the end the guy sacrificed himself to the monsters and joined them in the underground. Its pretty old movie i think i watched it somewhere in the 90's or early 20's

Sounds like Don't Be Afraid of the Dark but that's 2010

There's the 1972 film Death Line where mutants live on the Underground.  The Piccadilly Line between Holborn and Russell Square.

Bleeders has elements of your question. Underground dwelling, light sensitive mutants(on the small side) running around in tunnels. The hero joins them in the end as well. Here is the last 15 minutes of the movie (in German sadly) but adequate to validate this is the film.
Bleeders Finale

Omg i watched the trailer of bleeder and this is the movie that im looking for, thank you so much! When i was kid i dont understand the ending, why the hero guy joined those monsters but after watching the trailer, it pretty explains to me that the guy is somehow related or one of those mutant monsters. again thank you so much
